# Unable to build kmodule.xml inside the jar in maven project

Tags: java, maven, classloader, drools

I am facing an issue while accessing the /resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml file from the jar. The while accessing the KieContainer empty. So unable to make the KieSession

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
    KieSession testKS= kContainer.newKieSession("testKS");
```

The error which I am getting from the kie library looks like this.

```
            cron4j::scheduler[45074ba122a86df425e4988100000160255af0af5f9889c0]::executor[45074ba122a86df44340e4fe00000160255b2b4764a15b9b]] - Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=jar:file:D:\ProjectKLocation\test.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml
```

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 11: jar:file:D:\ProjectLocation\test.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml
2017-12-05 06:27:00,721 [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession] ERROR [ThreadID -             cron4j::scheduler[45074ba122a86df425e4988100000160255af0af5f9889c0]::executor[45074ba122a86df44340e4fe00000160255b2b4764a15b9b]] - Unknown KieSession name: testKS

As we can see that the slashes are different in the url, So I was looking for a way that we can reverse the direction of the slashes in the url, which may allow to the program to location the kmodule.xml in the jar.Is there a way by which this can be done or any other way to access the kmodule.xml from the jar.